# Which key value database shouild I use?

Tags: database, nosql

Here's my problem:

The table will have key-value pairs and can have multiple values for same key.

```
Key    Value
K1      V1
K1      V2
K2      V2
K2      V3
```

I will have only one type of queries:

1. Retrieve all Keys which has all values(V(i), V(i + 1), ..., V(j)).

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try `mongodb`. You can store documents and query like that:

```
db.pairs.find(
   {
     value: { $in: [ v(i), v(i+1),...,v(j)] }
   }
)
```

To find all elements:

```
db.pairs.find(
   {
     value: { $all: [ v(i), v(i+1),...,v(j)] }
   }
)
```

Comment: I need all the values to be present and not just one of the values.

Comment: Then use '$all' instead of '$in': 'db.pairs.find(
   {
     value: { $all: [ v(i), v(i+1),...,v(j)] }
   }
),